# Cancelling a Direct Sum of Modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Does any one know how to prove the following claim:

***Claim.***
Suppose that $R$ is a local (not necessarily Noetherian) ring, $M$ and $N$ are finite $R$-modules. If $M \cong M \oplus N$ then $N = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $r(M)=\mathrm{dim}_{R(0)}(M(0))$, where $R(0)=R/m$ is the quotient of $R$ by its maximal ideal $m$ and $M(0)=M/mM$. Check that $r(M)=0$ implies $M=0$ (Nakayama's lemma) for a finitely generated module $M$, and that $r(M_1 \oplus M_2)=r(M_1)+r(M_2)$ for modules $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Comment: Thanks Steve, it's a good answer! I only add that I'm certain that r(-) is additive on split short exact sequences
$$
0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow M \oplus N \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0
$$
but I'm not sure if it is also exact for all short sequences.

Comment: @mr.bigproblem It's not additive over all SES's (I see that perhaps there is some confusion about this, so I will edit the question to make it clearer): take $R=k[x]/x^2$, and consider the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow (x) \rightarrow R \rightarrow k \rightarrow 0$.